# How to send data to server with Jeditable select?

Tags: jquery, datatable, jeditable

I'm trying about a long time to send data to the server with my Jeditable. How can i do that?

```
oTable.$('td.select').editable('{{path('tool_admin_selectJeditable')}}', {
         "height": "14px",
         type: "select",
         submit: 'OK',
         loadurl: "{{path('tool_admin_selectJeditable')}}",
         loaddata: function(value, settings) {
              return {foo: "bar"};
         },
         cancel: 'Cancel',
         "width": "100%"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
oTable.$('td.select').editable('{{path('tool_admin_selectJeditable')}}', {
     "height": "14px",
     type: "select",
     submit: 'OK',
     onsubmit: function(settings, td) {
         //enter code to post data here
         $.post { .... }
     },
                        }
     loadurl: "{{path('tool_admin_selectJeditable')}}",
     loaddata: function(value, settings) {
          return {foo: "bar"};
     },
     cancel: 'Cancel',
     "width": "100%"
```

});

Comment: Thanks for answering, but it don't do what I want.

I need to post data before submiting new value to the server.

For example, the select input won't contain the same data if the users clic on third row, first colon, thant if he clic on fourth colon, first row...etc

So i have to post to the server informations about the cell cliqued, and the server must return json data in terms of